# Is JIT-compiler required for JIT-ROP attack?

Tags: web-browser, exploit, attacks, shellcode, rop

I have been studying up on the concept of Just-in-Time (JIT) ROP attack (https://cs.unc.edu/~fabian/papers/oakland2013.pdf), and came across this question which I have not been able to find the definite answer.

In the above paper, the authors state that their attack is **not** related to JIT compilers, and the term JIT is simply used to denote that the payload is generated **during the runtime**.

However, in their JIT-ROP architecture, they uses LLVM (which has JIT compilation) and from reading this SoK regarding JIT attacks (https://www.usenix.org/conference/woot18/presentation/gawlik), the authors state

> we surveyed the affected targets on the x86 and ARM architecture and **established a connection to code-reuse attacks which abuse JIT compilers**

which makes me believe that the JIT-compilers are indeed needed in order to successfully launch JIT-ROP attack (personally I think JIT is needed, since you need to be able to recompile victim's source code with found API pointers + necessary gadgets during runtime with escalated privilege). Also alot of JIT-related attacks are launched in the web browsers such as Chrome (V8), Firefox (IonMonkey) and Microsoft Edge (Chakra).

Could someone please clarify whether JIT-compiler is required to launch JIT-ROP attack?

Comment: Are you asking if the _attacker_ needs a JIT compiler, or if the target browser does?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been cleared on that regard. I meant the attacker (regardless of the target).

Comment: What is your definition of _required_? You can write bytecode without a compiler.

Comment: In this case, I believe my definition of required is whether the JIT compiler is required in order to compile the ROP payload. 

From my understanding of bytecode, it is a low-level code (intermediate representation?) which is useful in a different kind of JIT attack that do not leverage ROP payload. For the case of JIT-ROP attack, the adversaries are basically constructing a payload after dynamically finding the necessary gadgets during the runtime. Therefore, I was wondering whether JIT-ROP attack requires JIT-compiler, or any kind of compiler (such as gcc) is okay